# Applying function on columns of pandas data.frame is generating error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let say I have below pandas data.frame -

```
>>> Data
          Col1  Col2
53   08.02.2020 2020-02-14
55   01.02.2020 2020-02-13
335  30.01.2020 2020-02-14
365  14.02.2020 2020-02-16
446  11.02.2020 2020-02-15
476  03.02.2020 2020-02-18
504  08.02.2020 2020-02-10
557  01.02.2020 2020-02-15
668  10.02.2020 2020-02-15
756  07.02.2020 2020-02-08
```

Next, I have below function -

```
is_ten_char = lambda x: x.str.len().eq(10)
```

But, applying this function to columns to check the number of characters generates error -

```
Data[is_ten_char(Data.Col1) & is_ten_char(Data.Col2)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5270, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py", line 187, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 2041, in __init__
    self._inferred_dtype = self._validate(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 2098, in _validate
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Any pointer what is going wrong here will be highly helpful.

Comment: Maybe your column is not `str` type, but `datetime`. You can check with `df.dtypes`

Comment: If it is datetime, is there any way to convert to str on fly?

Comment: `Data.Col1.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Col1` is clearly not a datetime format as shown
- `Col2` probably is a datetime format, so to compare it as a string, do the follwoing

```py
is_ten_char = lambda x: x.str.len().eq(10)
Data[is_ten_char(Data.Col1) & is_ten_char(Data.Col2.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]
```

- However, this does not convert `Col2` to a string

  - `print(Data['Col2'][53])` >>> `Timestamp('2020-02-14 00:00:00')`
- If you want `Col2` converted to a string

  - `Data.Col2 = Data.Col2.dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d')`
  - Then use the original code